# Visual Studio - Connect dialog when running project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

Every time I run a project I get a dialog to connect to a database. And after setting a database and hitting ok I get the dialog saying: There where build errors while there actually where none.

I'm running Windows 10 Anniversary Update + Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

[image]

Comment: Could you share us the screenshot of that strange error dialog? Are there any error messages in the Visual Studio error list? You can change the MSBuild output verbosity to 'Diagnostic' to check the error list information. Besides, did you build your project before running it? Can you build it successfully? Those messages will help us to narrow down this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was filling in the Target Connection String on the properties of the project

[image]

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT thanks! I will mark this as the answer as soon as I can. Only after 5 hours from now.